# Oracle Datapump export/import

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to copy data b/w two databases and both sit on different servers. Both are Oracle 10g.

On my pc, i am connected to live database through Toad and there is 10g client installed on my pc.

Through Toad i am trying to export data dump file but on my pc i can't find expdp.exe file, i think this component is not installed on my pc.

> How can i install expdp.exe on my pc?
>
> Can i export data dump files on my pc(network) and not on server?
>
> By default, dump files are copied on server, but can i copy and paste them on my pc and then use those file to import data on different server through Toad.

Comment: The expdp and impdp utilties are not installed with the regular Oracle client as far as I know. I think you need an "administrative client" not sure about the naming.

Comment: Just run the installer again, do a custom install, and add the Oracle Database Utilities to your installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files for the Oracle datapump export/import can only reside on the same server as the Oracle database. If Oracle client was installed on your PC, you should have expdp/impdp utilities. Just make sure you call them from command line, not from Toad.

So, to summarize. To transfer data from one Oracle server to another:

- run expdp from your PC
- copy the dump file from the server to your PC; it might be wise to also grab the generated log file while you are at it
- copy the dump file from your PC to another server
- run impdp from your PC

Comment: Somehow expdp.exe file is missing on my pc. Do i need to reinstall the 10g client? Silly question though, Anyway to copy and paste that file from the server? Or can i point Toad to use expdp.exe file from server?

Comment: I believe expdp and impdp are installed with Oracle Client. I have Oracle 11g right now, but I'm quite certain I was using these utilities with Oracle 10g and didn't need anything installed on my PC beyound Oracle Client.

Comment: You do have to specifically install them if you don't do a full client install. I believe they're in the "Database Utilities" section of the product list.

Comment: DCookie, i will install this utility from the oracle client DVD. For now i managed to export the dump file from different pc which had EXPDP.exe file and after copying the dump file to server i was able to import it from that same pc.

Answer (score 3):

As other have already mentioned you DataPump cannot use files outside of the database server.

You don't need the expdp and impdp utilities installed locally however. You can start DataPump jobs through SQL by using the [DBMS_DATAPUMP package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_DATAPUMP.html#GUID-AEA7ED80-DB4A-4A70-B199-592287206348)

Here are some examples on how to use the package:

- http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump
- http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_datapump.html

Answer (score 2):

The data pump utility will move schemas and data between two databases with less work than importing and exporting dump files.  Oracle recommends it as the successor to imp and exp.

- Verify that the directory DATA_PUMP_DIR exists or create it.
- Use or create a user on the destination database who has read and write on that directory and DBA privilege
- verify or create a database link from destination to the source
- on the destination database drop the users whose schema and data you wish to recreate
- on the destination database run a script like this

  SET NLS_LANG=  your language

  SET ORACLE_SID = your database name

  impdp  import_user/destination_database_name directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR
  network_link=link_name schemas= user1,user2 LOGFILE=Import.log
  TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE

This is windows syntax and will differ for Linux. Substitute your database names, schemas and link names.

Answer (score 2):

For the cases shown here, the only difference between imp/exp and impdp/expdp is where the .dmp file ends up.  If you use exp from your PC, then the file will be on your PC and you don't have to move it from the Oracle server.  In our shop only the DBAs have access to the server, so exp is what I use.